# Extracting several elements using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have these two tables in my database :

```
table_A:             table_B:                  

id    user           id    user               
1     Mike           1     Mike          
2     Dan            2     Dan           
3     Tom            3     Tom
4     Lina           4     Lina
                     5     Cynthia
                     6     Sam
```

And i'm using this SQL query, to detect which users in table_B do not exist in table_A, and select those users (not existing in table A) ids:

```
SELECT table_B.id FROM table_B WHERE table_B.id NOT IN (SELECT table_A.id FROM table_A);
```

And i'm using this php script to put the ids in a variable $not:

```
 $sql=" SELECT table_B.id FROM table_B WHERE table_B.id NOT IN (SELECT table_A.id FROM table_A)";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            if (!$result) {
                printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
                exit();
            }
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                 $not=$row[0];
            }
```

Now if i want to extract 2 elements with my sql query:

```
 SELECT table_B.id, table_B.name FROM table_B WHERE table_B.id NOT IN (SELECT table_A.id FROM table_A);
```

How can i place both, each in a variable using the above script, so i'll be able to insert each element in a different table in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the values in a multidimensional array.

```
$not = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $not[] = array(
        "id" => $row['id'],
        "name" => $row['name']
    );
}

echo $not[0]['id']; //Returns 5
echo $not[0]['name']; //Returns Cynthia
echo $not[1]['id']; //Returns 6
echo $not[1]['name']; //Returns Sam
```

Comment: now if i want to insert the id element in a different table, what can i do? i use the variable like so:  $not[]['id'] ?

Comment: `$not[0]['id']` has an id take a look at all the echo's I've added.

Comment: yeah but this means i'll have to specify each element. What if i have hundreds of rows

Comment: You'll loop with a `foreach` through the array `$not`

Answer (score 0):

in your query define table_B.id as user_id and table_B.name as user

then in your php use mysqli_fetch_object like this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
    $not= $row;
    //or if you want to store all the results use $not[] = $row; and define $not as array

}
```